# Cannot get minted and beamer to work together in MikTex

Tags: beamer, listings, miktex, minted

Edit: This was solved by changing \begin{frame} to \begin{frame}[fragile] as suggested by @ulrike-fischer.
Here is a detailed answer: https://pbelmans.ncag.info/blog/2011/02/20/why-latex-beamer-needs-fragile-when-using-verbatim/

---

I want to use Rust and Listings does not support it, as far as I could see. So I wanted to use minted, but there are some problems with the beamer document-class. There are some related topics here, but I couldn't find a solution that solves my case.

This is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{minted}{Rust}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works fine, the export is what I want. So it shouldn't be connected to a failing python lib or something:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{Rust}
fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

If it helps, these are the last lines from the log file:

````
  Extraneous input ` fn main() { println!("Hello World!"); } \end {minted} \end {beamer@frameslide}\ifbeamer@twoscreenstext \beamer@dosecondscreennow {\begin {minted}{Rust} fn main() { println!("Hello World!"); } \end {minted} }\fi \ifbeamer@anotherslide \advance \beamer@slideinframe by 1\relax \relax \expandafter \iterate \fi \let \iterate \relax \beamer@writeslidentry \beamer@reseteecodes ' between \begin{minted}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}

l.12 \end{frame}

This input will be discarded. Hit <return> to continue.

)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> ...chris.000/Documents/Uni/SiW/min_example.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ...chris.000/Documents/Uni/SiW/min_example.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)```
````

Comment: `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: Wow, that worked. Easy. Thank you. No I have to read what the fragile part does.